# Python OOP - Change class text

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

Hi i wanna change the default text of a `class`. like `__str__` or `__repr__` for `object`

```
class Force(SIUnit):
    name = "Force"
    symbol = "F"
    unit = "N"


print(f"F = 1000{Force}")
```

something like this.

Comment: A force is not a kind of SI unit. It's a concept that can be measured in newtons (the SI unit) or pounds (the imperial unit) or some other kind of unit. If anything, you might create an *instance* of `SIUnit` that has its name attribute set to "newton"`, symbol attribute set to `"N"`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `__str__` on metaclass:

```py
class StringClassMeta(type):
    def __str__(cls):
        return cls.unit

class Force(metaclass=StringClassMeta):
    unit = 'N'

print(f'F = 1000 {Force}')
# F = 1000 N
```